# Why one cannot use a method in ng-class with condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple `loop` over the `ng-repeat` that display the text.
Also, I want one of the items from the list, that should be *active* (by highlighting using *green* color), as I have set a `variable` equal to the value of one of the item's `id`.

This does works well, when compared using the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'active': item.id == selectedId">
```

But when I try to incorporate a method, it just fails and gives console [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=null&p3=%7B%27active%27:%20getSelectedItemActive(item.id)&p4=%7B%27active%27:%20getSelectedItemActive(item.id)).

Please find the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/72hsmhr0/).

Code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'text 1'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'text 2'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'text 3'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'text 4'
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'text 5'
  }];

  $scope.selectedId = 3;

  $scope.getSelectedItemActive = function(id){
  return id == $scope.selectedId;
  }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the expression in your template (the '}'):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)">
```

should be

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)}">
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72hsmhr0/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing closing curly bracket in your ng-class.

Try using this it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is self explanatory -

> VM59 angular.js:9101 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token
>   'undefined' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column null of the
>   expression [{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)] starting at
>   [{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)].

Missed "}"

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data" ng-class="{'active': getSelectedItemActive(item.id)}">
```